# Comment-box bug in mobile Stack Exchange app for iOS

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app

I’m not a native English speaker, and therefore very often I prepare my texts in a Google Translate application, copy it to the clipboard, and paste in a desired place. 
The problem is that I can’t paste any text into the comment box below a question/answer.

Is it a bug, or some sort of security stuff?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhoneXs (iPhone11,2)
- OS Version: Version 12.0.1 (Build 16A405)